# 100% height div inside table td

Tags: html, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="height: 100%">Some Content</div>
        </td>
        <td>
             Some Content<br><br><br><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`<div>` height should be `100%` inside `<td>`, but height of `<td>` is not specified.
There should be some simple solution.

Comment: Do you mean 100% of the viewport?

Comment: `</td>` instead of `/td>` in second `<td>`

Comment: why would you want a div inside a td?

Comment: Do you mean 100% of the page or 100% of the `td`? In case the latter, both `td` and `div` will size themselves based on its content, unless specified.

Comment: 100% height of td.. but height of that td is depended on height of right td.. because it's longer. So I want to stretch div 100% inside left td..

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JnJmb/

Comment: yes, that's it! what is the solution?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a simple solution - `height:100%` works only if one of the containers has a set height. There are hacks, which I wouldn't recommend. One of them is to set `display:table` on the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JnJmb/67/)

You can use:

```
<td style="vertical-align:top;">Top</td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle;">Middle</td>
<td style="vertical-align:bottom;">Bottom</td>
<td style="vertical-align:54%;">Custom</td>
// More information on: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp
```

On the table cell to position the content correctly. You still however get background coloring issues where you probably want to apply any color directly to the table cell like so:

```
<td style="background-color:yellow;"></td>
```

Information on table row heights:

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user
>   agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the
>   row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the
>   row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells. A 'height'
>   value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used for layout
>   is MIN. MIN depends on cell box heights and cell box alignment (much
>   like the calculation of a line box height). CSS 2.1 does not define
>   how the height of table cells and table rows is calculated when their
>   height is specified using percentage values. CSS 2.1 does not define
>   the meaning of 'height' on row groups. [Source W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout)

- I have done inline css remember to always separate css using style sheets.

It seems that the div height is restricted to the cell's height, we can manipulate the cell height in pixels. 100% will only ever give you 100% of a cells min-height so you'll have to define it in pixels or some of form of dimension up to you.